# Nextgen gallery: show album inside a part of a page

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I'm using `Nextgen-Gallery` to show gallery in my WP website.

inside **a gallery page** the blue section shows the gallery pictures, and the red section suppose to show the album which contains the galleries.

after a long research on google I couldn't find anyway to accomplish the above (most answers was old and doesn't work with the latest version), so I thought maybe the following trick would do the job:

I created a new page and I added the shortcode `[album id=2 template=extend]` which works fine on that page, BUT when I try to include this page in the red section of **"a gallery page"** it shows the shortcode text instead of showing the galleries.

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Albums</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php 
                $post = get_post(107);    <--Here
                echo $post->post_content;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I show the galleries inside the red section?

Answer (score 0):

I browsed the Nextgen-Gallery source code and is huge, so solving this particular issue might not be easy.

I believe that the key is that the shortcode replacement takes place inside [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content), and won't happen if you just echo the raw post content.

Perhaps if you rewrote the php remplate to use that function it could work

```
 <?php 
     $post = get_post(107);    <--Here
     the_content();
 ?>
```

Comment: i just tried both `the_content();` and `echo the_content();` didn't work

Comment: the whole trick maybe is not the solution since Nextgen was made this way, do you have another solution?

Comment: Hmm you could try using the function [do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) so instead of retrieving post 107 and echoing its content you outright call for ```echo do_shortcode('[album id=2 template=extend]');```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are just printing the raw data, and since no postdata for this post is set, functions like `the_content()` ( where all sort of filters are applied, including `do_shortcode` ), will not work.

Use:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
```

If that does not work, then the problem is in shortcode.